# How to sort dropdown output alphabetically

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to sort an output of the props Alphabetically.

```
{
util.getDropDown(

_.sortBy(util.Names(this.props.abc)

))}
```

`_.sortBy(util.Names(this.props.abc) )`   //  i'm expecting

`this.props.abc` output need to be alphabetically sorted

I expect the output of dropdown containing `b,c,a to be a,b,c` but dropdown remains the same.

Comment: _.sortBy returns the newly sorted Array. It doesn't alter your array

Comment: @DTul ,

so any other method to alter an array ,

if not how can i proceed with _sortBy method , kindly help me out .

Comment: [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) native js function alters the array. Or you could just return the getDropDown function to your dropdown options. But for this we would need to see more of the code to be of any help.